# cannot set column int to be null. please use dbnull instead in datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching data from datarow and facing issue when there is null value in a row column. How can I change the below mentioned code to read null values??

```
Datarow dr_Out[j] = dr1.Field<double?>("" + Convert.ToString(columnNames[j]) + "");
```

at this line when there is null value below error occur.

```
cannot set column int to be null. please use dbnull instead in datarow
```

after adding DBNull facing this

[image]

Comment: Try adding `?? (object)DbNull.Value` to the end

Comment: ?? (object)DBNull.Value

Answer (score 4):

You can do as suggested by the error:

```
    dr_Out[j] = DBNull.Value;
    double? myValue = dr1.Field<double?>("" + Convert.ToString(columnNames[j]) + "");

    if(myValue != null)
    {
        dr_Out[j] = myValue;
    }
```

Comment: This will skip my step, my need is if there is null value then read that null and pass null value

Comment: And you need to write DBNull (capital B)

Answer (score 1):

I always define my classes to accept nulls.

eg:

```
public DateTime? updatedTime { get; set; }
```

and compare for nulls in the code.

```
dr["updatedTime"] = (e.updatedTime is null) ? DBNull.Value : e.updatedTime;
```

this way it forces a "proper" null suitable for DBs.